# Create podman volume with custom path

Tags: containers, rhel, podman

I am trying to create a volume with custom path, I want the volume data path to be /home/$USER/data instead of default path which is `~/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes`.

I have googled it but could not find the result, so I got help from chatGPT, then as per the guidance I have created the volume using below command:

```
podman volume create -o device=/home/$USER/data myvol
```

the volume got created

```
podman volume inspect myvol

     {
          "Name": "myvol",
          "Driver": "local",
          "Mountpoint": "/home/noor/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/myvol/_data",
          "CreatedAt": "2023-03-01T15:58:43.923688206+05:30",
          "Labels": {},
          "Scope": "local",
          "Options": {
               "device": "/home/noor/data"
          },
          "MountCount": 0,
          "NeedsCopyUp": true,
          "NeedsChown": true
     }
```

but when I run the container I get the below error.

```
podman run -it -d --name apache -v myvol:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs -p 8080:80 httpd
Error: error mounting volume myvol for container 0715cd8b6a02ac6ff069c2053a40992e4cacfff1d18fad6fa0e12b551dc10335: mount: /home/noor/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/myvol/_data: permission denied.
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you also need to specify `-o=o=bind`

```
$ mkdir ~/data
$ podman volume create \
      -o device=/home/$USER/data \
      -o=o=bind \
      myvol
myvol
$ podman run \
    -it \
    -d \
    --name apache \
    -v myvol:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs \
    -p 8080:80 \
     docker.io/library/httpd
7642c34e76ed0f34ed77f092c3a7cec7bfbf7b4344f0d7068658fb000042a392
$
```

I used **podman 4.4.2** on **Fedora 37** and
found the command here
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12013#issuecomment-1017998512

(The GitHub issue comment also specifies `-o type=none`. I guess it's not needed)